# Merge specific rows in pandas Df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df after read_excel where some of values (from one column, with strings) are divided. How can i merge them back?

for example:
the df i have

```
{'CODE': ['A', None, 'B', None, None, 'C'],
'TEXT': ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'b', 'C'],
'NUMBER': ['1', None, '2', None, None,'3']}
```

the df i want

```
{'CODE': ['A','B','C'],
'TEXT': ['Aa','Bbb','C'],
'NUMBER': ['1','2','3']}
```

I can't find the right solution. I tried to import data in different ways but it also did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward fill missing values or `None`s for groups with aggregate `join` and first non `None` value for `NUMBER` column:

```
d = {'CODE': ['A', None, 'B', None, None, 'C'],
'TEXT': ['A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'b', 'C'],
'NUMBER': ['1', None, '2', None, None,'3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df1 = df.groupby(df['CODE'].ffill()).agg({'TEXT':''.join, 'NUMBER':'first'}).reset_index()
    
print (df1)
  CODE TEXT NUMBER
0    A   Aa      1
1    B  Bbb      2
2    C    C      3
```

You can generate dictionary:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['CODE'])
d1 = dict.fromkeys(cols, 'first')
d1['TEXT'] = ''.join

df1 = df.groupby(df['CODE'].ffill()).agg(d1).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thats works great thanks. If I had different df (different number of columns) how to adjust this code? Do I need to list all the column names every time (as in Number)?

Comment: @PanAmigo - yes, how many column is there?

Comment: the problem is that it can be a different number (depends on the document), I have to do it quite universally
that's why I was looking for the ability to combine entire rows, without the need to indicate a column

Comment: @PanAmigo - Question is how aggregation? 10 columns by firt , 1 column by join? Or it depends?

Comment: the pattern is that one join the rest fill (only one value is divided to many rows)

Comment: @PanAmigo - check `print (d1)` - it geenrate dictioanry by  all columns without `
CODE`